# HP Laser Jet - different paper sizes list on iOS and macOS

Tags: macos, ios, printing

When I try to print an A6 document on my HP Laser Jet Printer, I can simply select everything on my macOS, and it looks like this:

[image]

On iOS, however, the A6 option does not appear. Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suspect this is the difference between having printer drivers and using AirPrint. Are you actually intending to print on A6 paper..?

Comment: yes... exactly A6 only